# Why is the value negative? AMPL

Tags: linear-programming, ampl

I developed an LP model where it allocates the number of cassava crackers to the declared number of stores depending on their minimum demand.

I have a concern because when I ran the code in AMPL, there's a negative value and I don't want to have negative values on the result.

Result after running the MOD FILE

```
ampl: include please.run;
CPLEX 20.1.0.0: optimal solution; objective 606000
0 dual simplex iterations (0 in phase I)
X :=
1 1   40
1 2   80
2 1   60
2 2   30
3 1   60
3 2   40
;

Y :=
1 1 1    20
1 1 2    20
1 1 3     0
1 2 1    80
1 2 2     0
1 2 3     0
2 1 1    60
2 1 2     0
2 1 3     0
2 2 1   -10
2 2 2     0
2 2 3    40
3 1 1    20
3 1 2     0
3 1 3    40
3 2 1    20
3 2 2    20
3 2 3     0
;
```

MOD FILE

```
#Parameters
param m; #cassava cracker types
param n; #periods
param o; #process
param r; #machines
param w; #store branches


#Sets
set I := 1..m; #index of cassava crackers types
set J := 1..n; #index of periods
set K := 1..o; #index of process
set L := 1..r; #index of machines
set S := 1..w; #index of store branches


#Parameters
param Production_Cost {i in I, j in J}; #production cost of cassava crackers i per pack in period j
param Cassava_Produce {i in I, j in J}; #kg of cassava needed to produce crackers
param Cassava_Avail {j in J}; #availability of cassava in period j (kg) 
param Process_Time {k in K}; #process time k
param Man_HoursAvail {k in K, j in J}; #availability of man hours for process k in period j (hour)
param Machine_Processing {l in L}; #processing time of machine l
param Machine_HoursAvail {l in L, j in J}; #availablity of machine hours l in period j
param Lowest_Sales {i in I, j in J}; #lowest sales of cassava crackers i in period j
param Highest_Sales {i in I, j in J}; #highest sales of cassava crackers i in period j
param Min_Demand {s in S}; # minimum demand of store branch s


#Decision Variable
var X {i in I, j in J};
var Y {i in I, j in J, s in S};


#Objective Function
minimize Cost: sum {i in I, j in J} Production_Cost[i,j]*X[i,j];

#Constraints
s.t. Raw_Material {j in J}: sum {i in I} Cassava_Produce[i,j]*X[i,j] <= Cassava_Avail[j];
s.t. Man_Hours {k in K, j in J}: sum {i in I} Process_Time[k]*X[i,j] <= Man_HoursAvail[k,j];
s.t. Machine_Hours {l in L, j in J}: sum {i in I} Machine_Processing[l]*X[i,j] <= Machine_HoursAvail[l,j];
s.t. Product_Sale {i in I, j in J}: Lowest_Sales[i,j] <= X[i,j] <= Highest_Sales[i,j];
s.t. Nonnegative {i in I, j in J}: X[i,j] >= 0;

s.t. C1 {i in I, j in J}: sum {s in S} Y[i,j,s] = X[i,j];
s.t. C2 {j in J, s in S}: sum {i in I} Y[i,j,s] >= Min_Demand[s];
```

Comment: If you could provide a mathematical formulation instead of copying the code separately, will give you more chances to answer your question. :)

Comment: `var Y {i in I, j in J, s in S} >= 0;`

Answer (score 2):

You are not bounding $Y_{i,j,s}$ from below and hence have to add a nonnegativity constraint similar to the one for $X_{i,j}$.

As long as $ \sum_{s \in S} Y_{i,j,s} $ is larger or equal to zero (ensured by C1), everything will work fine. However the individual values of $Y_{i,j,s}$ can take values smaller than zero.

**Minimum working example:**
Lets assume that you have 5 $Y$ variables for a given $s$ and a minimum demand of $s$ of 100. By assumption one of the $Y$ variables takes a value of -100. As long as the remaining four values sum up to at least 200, no constraint will be violated.